# How to change Ubuntu mate loading screen

Tags: 14.04

How can I change the ubuntu mate loading screen ehich comes just before login box.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate is no officially recognized Ubuntu flavor, and thus off topic here. You could search for help in the [MATE desktop forums](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/).

Comment: I thought Mate is an official flavor, or is going to be very shortly?

Comment: @Galgalesh They're working on it, but as of right now it's not an official flavor - thus it's *technically* OT.

Answer (score 0):

Super Boot Manager is a simple gui created with buc. This interface has the main purpose to make easier and intuitive configuration of Grub, Burg (Brand-new Universal loadeR from GRUB) and Plymouth. This interface also allows the installation of Burg, the installation of many graphic themes for Burg and Plymouth and it allows the creation of customized themes.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager

sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ingalex-super-boot-manager-trusty.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install super-boot-manager

sudo apt-get install -f

super-boot-manager

Good luck!